# How to update react testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

i want to use waitForElementToBeRemoved method for react-testing library and it says cannot find name "waitForElementToBeRemoved".

Below is my code,

```
waitForElementToBeRemoved(getByTestId('test-id'));
```

After clicking a button i will have to wait for domchange so i tried

```
await waitForDomChange(getByTestid('test-id'));
```

this gave timeout error for domchange.

i think i will have to update react testing library. how can i update it???

thanks.

Comment: Some async utilities have been deprecated in RTL, you should use waitFor instead of waitForDomChange : https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfordomchange-deprecated-use-waitfor-instead

Comment: thanks .also tried to use waitforelementtoberemoved and it was the same. should it work with waitforelementtoberemoved method?

Answer (score 0):

`import { waitForElementToBeRemoved } from "@testing-library/react";`

Comment: Please, always, explain your answer.